# Extract model info for large amount of regressions

Tags: r

I have a clinical data point that looks something like this:

```
patientid <- c(100,100,100,101,101,101,102,102,102,104,104,104)
outcome <- c(1,10,34,22,17,34,4,2,20,33,17,14)
time <- c(0,2,12,0,2,12,0,2,12,0,2,12)

Data <- data.frame(patientid=patientid, outcome=outcome, time=time)
```

Overall there is 700 patients with data at baseline, 2 years, and 12 years as represented by the timepoints. I want to run a regression for each patient (approximantely 700 lm) to account for within-patient variation and then extract the intercept and slope and make box and whisker plots.

So, I think an intial code would look like this. But still need to extract the intercept and slope for each model and then plot them with box and whisker.

```
regressions <- data %>% 
    group_by(patientid) %>% 
    do(fit = lm(outcome ~ time, data=.))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `broom` you will get a dataframe per id with all relevant values from the models. Here the code using your `Data` as input:

```
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
#Code
New <- Data%>% group_by(patientid) %>%
  do(fitmod = tidy(lm(outcome ~ time, data=.))) %>% 
  unnest(fitmod)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 6
  patientid term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
      <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1       100 (Intercept)     2.69     2.06      1.31   0.416 
2       100 time            2.64     0.293     8.99   0.0705
3       101 (Intercept)    18.6      4.12      4.52   0.139 
4       101 time            1.23     0.587     2.09   0.284 
5       102 (Intercept)     1.74     2.75      0.634  0.640 
6       102 time            1.48     0.391     3.79   0.164 
7       104 (Intercept)    26.8      7.55      3.55   0.175 
8       104 time           -1.17     1.08     -1.09   0.473
```

For the plot try this:

```
#Code 2
Data%>% group_by(patientid) %>%
  do(fitmod = tidy(lm(outcome ~ time, data=.))) %>% 
  unnest(fitmod) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(patientid),y=estimate,color=term))+
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.9))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=estimate-std.error,ymax=estimate+std.error),
                position = position_dodge(0.9))
```

Output:

[image]